# Strange behaviour of Reduce for Mod[x,1]

Tags: equation-solving

For every integer $x$ the equation `Mod[x, 1] == 0` holds. While

```
Simplify[Mod[x, 1] == 0, Element[x,Integers]]
```

gives `True`,

```
Reduce[Mod[x, 1] == 0, x, Integers]
```

gives `False`. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica @ StackExchange! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time you will be able to [do more on the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges) (post graphics, edit things, etc). Also, I have formatted your code to make it easier to read. [This link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) will show you how it's done for next time. And welcome again!

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi I think this is because the documentation is usually written by the same person that coded the functionality. While an economical approach, it's not necessarily the best for expository value: the author will already have internalized the purpose and semantics of the code, so describing it to others in an unbiased way is that much harder for them. I don't blame the developers for that, of course--I'm a terrible example of this myself.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I think you just described my papers :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Reduce` works fine for a slightly more sophisticated expression, e.g. :

```
Reduce[ ForAll[ x, x ∈ Integers, Mod[ x, 1] == 0], x]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

however there is a bug in `Solve` :

```
Solve[ Mod[x, 1] == 0, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

therefore it is not surprising we have an analogical issue in `Reduce` :

```
Reduce[ Mod[x, 1] == 0, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Seemingly  there has not been much clamor therefore it has not been a high priority to improve it.

One can work around these problems :

```
Reduce[ Mod[ a x, a] == 0 && a == 1, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> C[1] ∈ Integers && a == 1 && x == C[1]
> ```

or simply

```
Reduce[ Mod[ x, 1] == a, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> C[1] ∈ Integers && a == 0 && x == C[1]
> ```

```
Solve[ Mod[ x, 1] == a, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers && a == 0]}}
> ```

### Edit

The above problems with `Reduce` and `Solve` were found  in `Mathematica 8`. Before there had been :

**ver. 7**

```
Solve[ Mod[x, 1] == 0, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not
> be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >> 
>
> {{x -> InverseFunction[Mod, 1, 2][0, 1]}}
> ```

```
Reduce[ Mod[x, 1] == 0, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Now these bugs have been fixed :

**ver. 9**

```
Solve[ Mod[x, 1] == 0, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
> ```

```
Reduce[ Mod[x, 1] == 0, x, Integers]
```

> ```
> C[1] ∈ Integers && x == C[1]
> ```

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Comment: Worth noting that this issue has been fixed in *Mathematica* 9, where `Solve` now gives the correct result.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks, updated.