# Solving/Reducing equations in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: equation-solving, options, warning-messages, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I was trying to find all the numbers $n$ for which $2^n=n\mod 10^k$ using *Mathematica*.
My first try:

```
Reduce[2^n == n, n, Modulus -> 100]
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>
```

using $n^2$ instead of $2^n$ works just fine, where is the problem with $2^n\;$?

On top of that, how do I keep the modulus $10^k$ variable and therefore, receive a solution dependent on $k\;$?

Comment: This is how it would be done in Maple:
`msolve(2^n = n, 100); {n = 36}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem we encounter here  is an instance of rather unexpected limitations of equation solving functionality (i.e. `Modulus` option in `Reduce`), e.g. this question : [Strange behaviour of Reduce for Mod[x,1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/strange-behaviour-of-reduce-for-modx-1) provides another example which has been fixed in the newest version (`9.0`) of `Mathematica`. Since `Modulus` unexpectedly doesn't work here we can take advantage of the `Mod` function.  The main issue here is that there are infinitely many solutions and even though one might classify them easily, the task of finding a general solution is not straightforward in `Mathematica`. Taking this into account one should assume some bounds on `n`. If we do so, given a small integer `k > 0`, we can find all solutions in a given range, e.g. for `k == 2` :

```
Reduce[ Mod[ 2^n - n, 100] == 0 && 0 < n < 10^3, n, Integers]
```

> ```
> n ==  36 || n == 136 || n == 236 || n == 336 || n == 436 || n == 536 ||
> n == 636 || n == 736 || n == 836 || n == 936
> ```

Increasing the range of `n` we might ensure that the general form of the solution for `k == 2` should be `n == 100 m + 36` for `m ∈ Integers && m >= 0` and then we could proceed in order to prove an appropriate mathematical theorem. For a general `k >= 1` the space of possible solutions to be explored is much wider, and restricting `k` e.g. this way `0 < k < n < 10^3` it takes much more time to find all solutions :

```
Reduce[ Mod[ 2^n - n, 10^k] == 0 && 0 < k < n < 10^3, {k, n}, Integers]
```

while for e.g. `0 < k < 10 < n < 10^3` we get the results almost immediately :

```
Solve[ Mod[ 2^n - n, 10^k] == 0 && 0 < k < 10 < n < 10^3, {k, n}, Integers] // Short
```

> ```
> { { k -> 1, n -> 14}, {k -> 1, n -> 16}, {k -> 1, n -> 34},
>   <<105>>, {k -> 2, n -> 836}, {k -> 2, n -> 936}, {k -> 3, n -> 736}}
> ```

**Edit 1**

Assuming `n` in a finite range we can still encounter messages, that the  system cannot be solved e.g. :

```
Reduce[ Mod[ 2^n - n, 10^5] == 0 && 10^(5 - 1) < n < 10^5, n, Integers]
```

> ```
> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>
> ```

A workaround (not very convenient) would be dividing the range `10^(5 - 1) < n < 10^5` into e.g. `9` equal ranges `m 10^4 < n < (m + 1) 10^4` for integer `m` :  `1 <= m <= 9`. A more systematic approach takes advantage of one of many `SystemOptions` like `ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints` (there is no separate documentation page for this option, nevertheless one finds necessary information here [Diophantine Polynomial Systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html#623839255) ), which by default is :

```
SystemOptions[ "ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints"]
```

> ```
> {"ReduceOptions" -> {"ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {1000, 10000}}}
> ```

increasing the last value we can find the only solution in a given range :

```
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {1000, 100000}];
Reduce[ Mod[ 2^n - n, 10^5] == 0 && 10^(5 - 1) < n < 10^5, n, Integers]
```

> ```
> n == 48736
> ```

to solve e.g. `Mod[ 2^n - n, 10^6] == 0 && 10^(6 - 1) < n < 10^6` we need to increase `ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints` even more , e.g. (it takes a few minutes to evaluate) :

```
SetSystemOptions[ "ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {10^6, 10^6}];
Reduce[ Mod[ 2^n - n, 10^6] == 0 && 10^(6 - 1) < n < 10^6, n, Integers]
```

> ```
> n == 948736
> ```

**Edit 2**

To prove a more general theorem we can use the results we've got so far. Assuming this form of the general solution for `k == 2` : `n == 100 m + 36` for `m ∈ Integers && m >= 0` we can demonstrate working with `Resolve` that in fact it is a solution in much wider range than we could do this with `Reduce` as above. Unfortunately we can't prove with `Mathematica` that it is a solution for all natural `m` because we have to assume a lower and upper bound, e.g. (evaluating it takes a few minutes) :

```
Resolve[ ForAll[ m, 0 < m <= 10^5 && m ∈ Integers, 
                 Mod[ 2^(100 m + 36) - 100 m - 36, 100] == 0]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Increasing `ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints` we found ~ 10000 solutions, while this way we showed that the result is true for all natural `m <= 10^5` in approximately the same time.

Comment: Reduce[ Mod[ 2^n - n, 10^k] == 0 && 10^(k-1) < n < 10^k, n, Integers] gives me the same error for k>=5. But in general, shouldnt this be evaluated almost immediately?

Comment: @CBenni You might play around e.g. with this : `Table[ Reduce[
  Mod[2^n - n, 10^4] == 0 && k 10^(4) < n < (k + 1) 10^(5 - 1), n, Integers], {k, 10}]`, while for `Mod[2^n - n, 10^5]` there is only `n == 48736`.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between $2^n$ and $n^2$ is that $2^n$ is not a function $\bmod 10$ -- that is, $2^{n+10}$ is not congruent to $2^n\bmod 10$.  Further $2^n$ is only eventually periodic $\bmod 10^k$, $k \geq 2$.  For instance $2^1$ is not congruent to any other $2^n \bmod 100$.  On the other hand, polynomial functions are all functions $\bmod\, m$ : `f[n+m]` is congruent to `f[n]`$\bmod\, m$. In short, exponential functions do not behave in the nice way polynomial functions do.

Instead of solving it as a modular equation, convert it to an explicit Diophantine equation:

```
Solve[ 2^n - n - q 10^k == 0 && 1 <= k <= 3 && 0 <= n < If[ k == 1, 2, 1] 10^k,
       {k, n, q}, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{k -> 1, n -> 14, q -> 1637}, {k -> 1, n -> 16, q -> 6552},
>  {k -> 2, n -> 36, q -> 687194767}, {k -> 3, n -> 736, 
>   q ->  3614737867146518396094859318021923665089733007170019231594754471\
>   5042481028623340798795186188738943961227492678378035156199978199883243\
>   4041296198795326329101623141899709787663433296905279066051548640942013\
>   290819886814068}}
> ```

The size of the quotient `q` for `k=3` suggests that a practical limit is being reached.  (I've had `k=4` running for over ten minutes, and it's time for me to move on.)