# How do I make Reduce yield all solutions explicitly?

Tags: equation-solving, finite-fields

Say I want to do the following:

```
Reduce[ x+y+z==1, {x,y,z}, Modulus -> 7 ]
```

then I get a solution with parameters, `C[1]` :

> ```
> x == 1 + 6 C[1] + 6 C[2] && y == C[2] && z == C[1]
> ```

Now, for non-linear equations, such as

```
Reduce[x + y^2 + z == 1, {x, y, z}, Modulus -> 7]
```

I get a complete list of solutions, here are the first `5` of them :

```
%[[ ;; 5]]
```

> ```
> (x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 1) || (x == 0 && y == 1 && z == 0) || 
> (x == 0 && y == 2 && z == 4) || (x == 0 && y == 3 && z == 6) ||
> (x == 0 && y == 4 && z == 6)
> ```

Is there a way to make the system yield this type of output also in the first case ? (Of course, I can just loop over all possibilities of the parameter and get a complete list, but I'd prefer to make *Mathematica* do it for me if it is possible.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This tutorial [Diophantine Polynomial Systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html#623839255) collects useful methods for tackling similar problems. There one finds e.g. :

> *Mathematica* enumerates the solutions explicitly only if the number of integer solutions of the system does not exceed the maximum of the $p^{th}$ power of the value of the system option DiscreteSolutionBound, where p is the dimension of the solution lattice of the equations...

That is a necessary but not sufficient condition. Increasing `DiscreteSolutionBound` (by default `10`) doesn't help here e.g.

```
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 1000];
```

On the other hand there are instances of limitations of `Reduce` when we work with the `Modulus` option (see e.g. : [Solving/Reducing equations in Z/pZ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/solving-reducing-equations-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz)) and most likely this is the case here.

Nonetheless one can make `Reduce` write all solutions explicitly. A straightforward way is to substitute all generated parameters (since they are protected) by another symbols, and using `Table` to write all cases. Then we have to use  `Mod[#, 7]&` since `Reduce[..., Modulus->7]` is inside  `Table`.

```
Flatten[
  Mod[ Table[{x, y, z} /.ToRules[ 
         Reduce[ x + y + z == 1, {x, y, z}, Modulus -> 7] ] /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> b},
         {a, 0, 6}, {b, 0, 6}],  7],  1]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {5, 3, 0}, {4, 4, 0}, {3, 5, 0}, {2, 6, 0},
>  {0, 0, 1}, {6, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 1}, {1, 6, 1}, 
>  {6, 0, 2}, {5, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}, {2, 4, 2}, {1, 5, 2}, {0, 6, 2}, 
>  {5, 0, 3}, {4, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 3}, {0, 5, 3}, {6, 6, 3}, 
>  {4, 0, 4}, {3, 1, 4}, {2, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {0, 4, 4}, {6, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 4}, 
>  {3, 0, 5}, {2, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 5}, {0, 3, 5}, {6, 4, 5}, {5, 5, 5}, {4, 6, 5}, 
>  {2, 0, 6}, {1, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 6}, {6, 3, 6}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 6}, {3, 6, 6}}
> ```

or we can use the `Mod` function more extensively in the integers with appropriate bounds on the variables `x, y, z` e.g.

```
Mod[{x, y, z} /. {ToRules[ Reduce[x + y + z == 1 && -10 < x < 10 &&
                                  -10 < y < 10 && -10 < z < 10, {x, y, z}, Integers]]
                 }, 7] // DeleteDuplicates
```

`Reduce` is recommended when we have non-linear equations. In a special case of linear equations namely the Frobenius equations $\; a_1 x_1 +\dots + a_n x_n =b \quad$ (where $a_i$ - positive integers, $x_i$ - nonnegative integers and $b$ is an integer) instead of working with `Reduce` in the integers we can use `FrobeniusSolve` for a much more efficient  approach  (see e.g. [Finding the number of solutions to a diophantine equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/finding-the-number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation)) :

```
Flatten[ Mod[ Table[ FrobeniusSolve[ {1, 1, 1}, 1 + 7 k], {k, 2}], 7], 1]//
DeleteDuplicates
```

All these  methods yield identical results with respect to the ordering.

Comment: But what if I have more than one linear equation, and/or do not know if the equations are linear?

Comment: Really only have to take k up to (1+1+1)-1, that is, 2. For coeffs {a,b,c} it would be (a+b+c)-1.

Comment: @Paxinum Then you can use `Reduce`, see edit.

Comment: Allright, Thanks! This is the solution I went for, but it seems a bit hackish. So, I suspected that it might be possible to do it in a more natural way, but apparently not...

Comment: One can also use `Block[{C}, Table[..., {C[1], 0, 6}, {C[2], 0, 6}]]`, instead of replacing the `C`s with `a`, `b` -- not an important difference, but it might suit someone's style.

Answer (score 4):

Making it a non-linear equation works :)

```
Reduce[(x + y + z - 1)^2 == 0, {x, y, z}, Modulus -> 7]
```

$$
(x=0\land y=0\land z=1)\lor (x=0\land y=1\land z=0)\lor (x=0\land y=2\land
   z=6)\lor (x=0\land y=3\land z=5)\lor (x=0\land y=4\land z=4)\lor
   (x=0\land y=5\land z=3)\lor (x=0\land y=6\land z=2)\lor (x=1\land
   y=0\land z=0)\lor (x=1\land y=1\land z=6)\lor (x=1\land y=2\land
   z=5)\lor (x=1\land y=3\land z=4)\lor (x=1\land y=4\land z=3)\lor
   (x=1\land y=5\land z=2)\lor (x=1\land y=6\land z=1)\lor (x=2\land
   y=0\land z=6)\lor (x=2\land y=1\land z=5)\lor (x=2\land y=2\land
   z=4)\lor (x=2\land y=3\land z=3)\lor (x=2\land y=4\land z=2)\lor
   (x=2\land y=5\land z=1)\lor (x=2\land y=6\land z=0)\lor (x=3\land
   y=0\land z=5)\lor (x=3\land y=1\land z=4)\lor (x=3\land y=2\land
   z=3)\lor (x=3\land y=3\land z=2)\lor (x=3\land y=4\land z=1)\lor
   (x=3\land y=5\land z=0)\lor (x=3\land y=6\land z=6)\lor (x=4\land
   y=0\land z=4)\lor (x=4\land y=1\land z=3)\lor (x=4\land y=2\land
   z=2)\lor (x=4\land y=3\land z=1)\lor (x=4\land y=4\land z=0)\lor
   (x=4\land y=5\land z=6)\lor (x=4\land y=6\land z=5)\lor (x=5\land
   y=0\land z=3)\lor (x=5\land y=1\land z=2)\lor (x=5\land y=2\land
   z=1)\lor (x=5\land y=3\land z=0)\lor (x=5\land y=4\land z=6)\lor
   (x=5\land y=5\land z=5)\lor (x=5\land y=6\land z=4)\lor (x=6\land
   y=0\land z=2)\lor (x=6\land y=1\land z=1)\lor (x=6\land y=2\land
   z=0)\lor (x=6\land y=3\land z=6)\lor (x=6\land y=4\land z=5)\lor
   (x=6\land y=5\land z=4)\lor (x=6\land y=6\land z=3)
$$

Comment: Interesting (+1), have you got any justification of the issue ?

Comment: This will work for a prime modulus, but not for one under which there is a non-trivial square-root of 0 (e.g. `Mod[6^2, 12] == 0`).

Comment: @Artes May be Mma explicitly checks for linearity, where it knows how to write parametrized solutions, and in non-linear case uses some other algorithms.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It can be taken into account 
    Reduce[Reduce[(x + y + z - 1)^2 == 0, {x, y, z}, Modulus -> 36], Modulus -> 6]

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way expand the solutions to a linear equation:

```
Evaluate@Reduce[x + y + z == 1, {x, y, z}, Modulus -> 7, 
    GeneratedParameters -> Slot] & @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 6], 2]

  (* {x == 1 && y == 0 && z == 0, x == 7 && y == 1 && z == 0, ...,
      x == 73 && y == 6 && z == 6} *)
```

There are two differences from the normal output of `Reduce`: the output is a list instead of a logical expression, and the values are not the least nonnegative residues modulo 7.  One can process the output to suit one's needs: `Apply` `Or`, reduce each `Integer` with `% /. n_Integer :> Mod[n, 7]`, convert to rules with `ToRule /@ %`, and so on.