# Solve[] unexpectedly giving empty solution sets for extremely large problems

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I was calculating the set of lattice vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^4$ which have taxicab norm $r$. For example, executing

```
Solve[Abs[c1] + Abs[c2] + Abs[c3] + Abs[c4] <= 2, {c1, c2, c3, c4}, Integers]
```

yields the 41 lattice vectors of taxicab norm 2 or less. This works fine up through $r=19$, at which point there are 97,281 solutions. However, at $r=20$,

```
Solve[Abs[c1] + Abs[c2] + Abs[c3] + Abs[c4] <= 20, {c1, c2, c3, c4}, Integers]
```

simply returns {{}}. According to the documentation, Solve[] yields {{}} "if the set of solutions is full-dimensional", which is clearly not the case for the above, which has a finite, though large, number of solutions.

Also, as far as I could tell, nowhere in the documentation does it specify that there is a cap on the number of possible solutions.

Question: *Is there are a reason for this? And is there a way to coax Solve[] into returning the correct answer?*

I know of the obvious though tedious mathematical tricks for reducing the problem into several lower-dimensional problems, but I'd like to solve it directly if possible.

Comment: _Mathematica_ also returns a Solve::fulldim warning. So `Reduce` should be used. You can find something useful here: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00223.html

Comment: @luyuwuli: Thanks, but the point of my question was that the problem is not full-dimensional; I am aware of the difference between Solve[] and Reduce[]. The issue is that the Solve[] is giving an incorrect result, namely giving a full-dimensional output without generating a Solve::fulldim warning on a problem which is not full-dimensional.

Comment: You'd better play with `Reduce` having set appropriate `"ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints"`. You can find a good example here: [Solving/Reducing equations in Z/pZ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/solving-reducing-equations-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz/16003#16003). It might be even more reasonable to make a neat use of `FrobeniousSolve`, here you can find an interesting example [Finding the number of solutions to a diophantine equation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/finding-the-number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation/10569#10569).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it as an alternate possibility! What's weird about my current method is that Solve[] and Reduce[] yield the same results for $r\leq 19$, but for $r\geq 20$ Solve[] is unable to give the correct answer, and does so without warning.

Comment: Why not this instead?: `crosspolytope[n_] := Flatten[Table[{c1, c2, c3, c4}, {c1, -n, n}, {c2, Abs[c1] - n,  n - Abs[c1]}, {c3, Abs[c1] + Abs[c2] - n, n - (Abs[c1] + Abs[c2])}, {c4, Abs[c1] + Abs[c2] + Abs[c3] - n, n - (Abs[c1] + Abs[c2] + Abs[c3])}], 3]`

Comment: @MichaelE2: That's undoubtedly better than just the brute-force Solve[] method. I'll consider this closed now :)

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus This post also should be interesting to you [How do I make Reduce yield all solutions explicitly?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18821/how-do-i-make-reduce-yield-all-solutions-explicitly/18826#18826). I didn't marked this question as a duplicate, but you should realize it is very closely related.