# Reduce[] giving incorrect result for equation over $\mathbb{Z}^4$

Tags: equation-solving

This is partially in response to a [question I posted earlier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39385/solve-unexpectedly-giving-empty-solution-sets-for-extremely-large-problems), although the problem in this case appears to be distinct from the problem there, so I am temporarily filing this as a separate question.

Executing

```
Length[Reduce[Abs[c1] + Abs[c2] + Abs[c3] + Abs[c4] <= 19, {c1, c2, c3, c4}, Integers]]
```

yields 97281, which is in full agreement with the result obtained when `Reduce` is replaced by `Solve`.

However, executing

```
Length[Reduce[Abs[c1] + Abs[c2] + Abs[c3] + Abs[c4] <= 22, {c1, c2, c3, c4}, Integers]]
```

yields 42736. This is obviously impossible, since the number of $\mathbb{Z}^4$ lattice points within a taxicab ball is a strictly increasing function of radius.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? I am going to temporarily solve the problem via alternate, more delicate approaches seeing as both `Solve[]` and `Reduce[]` have failed to give correct answers for $r\geq20$, but any insight as to this sudden behavioral discontinuity would be appreciated.

EDIT: It may be possible that the lower than expected result from `Length` may be due to `Reduce` outputting a solution set whose expression depth was not just that of the simple `Or[...]` structure that it normally gives for smaller values of $r$. If anyone can confirm this, I'll close this question.

Comment: I upvoted your last question. But this time, I really think it's your job to find out for certain whether the output actually is incorrect, rather than that it just has an unexpected structure.

Comment: At the very least, it contains this (call the result `sols` and then run this): `Cases[sols, Except@HoldPattern@And[__Equal], {1}]`. Is this right or wrong? I'm not sure. As this is also the last element, I think `Reduce` is just telling us that it gave up exhaustively enumerating solutions at that point.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Artes recently told me about the option "ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints", which I'll try fiddling with once I'm finished with dinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try:

```
ListLinePlot[{#, Length@Reduce[Abs[c1] + Abs[c2] + Abs[c3] + Abs[c4] <= # && 
                 And @@ Thread[{c1, c2, c3, c4} >= 0], {c1, c2, c3, c4}, Integers]} & /@ 
                                                                            Range[2, 20]]
```

You'll get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It only means that `Reduce[]` is expressing its results in a different way. Take a look at them and then post your own answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I looked at them and it's clear that it's decided to stop using exhaustive enumeration.