# How do I get all possible solutions in an underdetermined system?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I have two problems which I'd like to solve with *Mathematica*.

If I have a system of two equations with three unknowns, how can I get to list all possible solutions for the unknowns?

Here is what I have tried:

```
Solve[{ a + b + c == 5, 1/a + 1/b + 1/c == 1/5}, { a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >> 
>
> {{a -> 5, c -> -b}, {b -> 5, c -> -a}, {b -> -a, c -> 5}}
> ```

What would I change in this specific instance?

Here are the problems:

### I

Suppose that $a, b, c$ are real numbers satisfying $a+b+c=5$ and $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=+\frac{1}{5}$.
Find the greatest possible value of $a^3+b^3+c^3$

If I list all solutions I'll be able to choose all solutions maximizing $a^3+b^3+c^3$.

### II

Finding integers $x, y$ and $z$  that satisfy this system:
$$\quad x^2 y + y^2 z + z^2 x = 2186 $$
$$\quad x y^2 + y z^2 + z x^2 = 2188$$.
evaluate $x^2+y^2+z^2$

The both problems can be found [here](http://purplecomet.org/home/resource/543/2013HighSchoolProblems.pdf) (see exercises $27$ and $30$ ).

Comment: I have asked a specific question. Please let me know if you can help. @Artes

Comment: @Artes Is there a way to get a list of exact values instead of conditions? Also, Reduce does not seem to work.

Comment: `Reduce` works well, in any case you should study this post [How do I make Reduce yield all solutions explicitly?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18821/how-do-i-make-reduce-yield-all-solutions-explicitly).

Comment: @Artes How would I find the number of unknowns that satisfy certain conditions?

Comment: @Artes: *Very* nice post you did in the link, +1 there.

Comment: @rasher Thanks!

Comment: @Artes unaccepted

Comment: @user140900 I decided to complete your post with another question you asked (it wasn't clear at first what you wanted) since the first question might be a duplicate but another one is an interesting problem. So I decided to undelete my answer.

Comment: @Artes I can't remember what I wanted at the time. Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### I

Let's write down an appropriate system we would like to solve,
i.e. we are to maximize `a^3 + b^3 + c^3` knowing that `a + b + c == 5` and  `1/a + 1/b + 1/c == 1/5`, thus the most direct approach uses `Maximize` with adequate conditions:

```
Maximize[{a^3 + b^3 + c^3, a + b + c == 5, 1/a + 1/b + 1/c == 1/5}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {125, {a -> 1, b -> 5, c -> -1}}
> ```

With `Maximize` we can get only a **specific solution**, an example can be found here : [How do I determine the maximum value for a polynomial, given a range of x values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37225/how-do-i-determine-the-maximum-value-for-a-polynomial-given-a-range-of-x-values/37227#37227), nevertheless we can remedy this problem using Lagrange multipliers, see e.g. [How can I implement the method of Lagrange multipliers to find constrained extrema?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36847/how-can-i-implement-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-to-find-constrained-extre/36854#36854).
However since there is a symmetry between `a, b` and `c` we can conclude that any permutation of this triple `{a -> 1, b -> 5, c -> -1}` is also a solution.

There are another ways to solve the problem which can be examined with the answers to these questions:
[Am I missing anything? Solving Equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26147/am-i-missing-anything-solving-equations)
[Efficient code for solve this equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/efficient-code-for-solve-this-equation)

Let's provide the simplest:

```
Simplify[ a^3 + b^3 + c^3, {{a + b + c == 5, 1/a + 1/b + 1/c == 1/5}}]
```

> ```
> 125
> ```

### II

Another question provides a nice example where a simple usage of `Solve` and `Reduce` with an appropriate domain specification will not be sufficient.

E.g. this yields a complicated system returning the solution but it doesn't clarify if another solutions really exist.

```
Reduce[ x^2 y + y^2 z + z^2 x == 2186 && x y^2 + y z^2 + z x^2 == 2188 && 
        (x | y | z) ∈ Integers, {x, y, z}]
```

Thus we should approach the problem in a different way.
Let's notice that:

```
Simplify[ x y^2 + y z^2 + z x^2 - (x^2 y + y^2 z + z^2 x)]
```

> ```
> -(x - y) (x - z) (y - z)
> ```

Now we can conclude that using slightly different system we can find an appropriate solution:

```
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 /. Normal @ 
 Solve[ x - y == a && x - z == b && y - z == c && 
        x^2 y + y^2 z + z^2 x == 2186 && -a b c == 2, {x, y, z}, Integers]//Union//First
```

> ```
> 245
> ```