# How to solve this equation with integers as a solution?

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I want to solve the equation $$x^y + y = y^x + x$$
 with $x$, $y$ are integer numbers. I tried

```
Solve[x^y + y == y^x + x, {x, y}, Integers]
```

How to solve the above equation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, one should mathematically analyze the problem. Obviously there are infinitely many solutions of the form  `{1, y}` and `{x, 1}`, as well as `{x,y}` where `x == y`. So we can exclude such solutions from our search.
Another point is remembering `SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]`. There were questions dealing with them, so I'm not going to discuss these issues here; look at e.g. [Solving/Reducing equations in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16001).

Proceeding with similar problems, we should somehow restrict the search space. Of course, one can try e.g. `x < 1000` and `y < 1000`, but then you would have to play with e.g. `ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints`; on the other hand, if you try e.g.  `x < 100` and `y < 100`, then both `Reduce` and `Solve` work quite well:

```
Reduce[ x^y + y == x + y^x && 1 < x < 100 && 1 < y < 100 && x != y, {x, y}, Integers]
```

> ```
>  (x == 2 && y == 3) || (x == 3 && y == 2)
> ```

```
Solve[ x^y + y == x + y^x && 1 < x < 100 && 1 < y < 100 && x != y, {x, y}, Integers]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> 2, y -> 3}, {x -> 3, y -> 2}}
> ```

Now, one can be pretty sure that there are no other solutions besides `x == y`, as well as  `{1, y}` and `{x, 1}` for larger numbers. The argument comes from the behavior of the exponential functions.

---

**Edit**

To make it more clear what kind of argumentation might be sufficient to prove an adequate theorem, I suggest to proceed further starting with a simple observation.

There is a symmetry between `x` and `y`, so we can assume that e.g. `x` is greater than `y` and make a substitution with `k` being a positive integer:

```
-x^y - y + y^x + x /. x -> k + y // Simplify
```

> ```
>  k + y^(k + y) - (k + y)^y
> ```

Since we'd like to demonstrate that there are no different solutions besides those given above, let's plot the few first functions of the following family numbered with an integer parameter `k`:

```
f[ y_, k_Integer] := k + y^(k + y) - (k + y)^y
```

We know (see above) that these functions have roots at $y=1$; moreover, there is another root for $y > 1$, but we can simply prove that there is only one function for $k=1$ having another root at an integer point (namely $y=2$). All other functions have another root for $1 < y <2$:

```
Plot[ Tooltip @ Table[ f[y, k], {k, 5}], {y, 1, 2.3}, Evaluated -> True,
      PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> {-1, 2}]
```

[image: plots of f[y, k]]

The formal proof is a simple exercise.