# Solving a diophantine equation with three variables

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve this equation using Mathematica:

$2^x + 113^y = z^2$, $\operatorname{gcd}(x, y) = 1$.

Comment: Exponential Diophantine equations are difficult in general. That being said, look at `Reduce[]` and `FindInstance[]`.

Comment: Isn't this two equations in three unknowns?

Answer (score 8):

Dealing with diophantine equations after appropriate restriction of the possible solution space  one could play with extension of `ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints`.

```
SystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints"]
```

For an example when an extension appears crucial see e.g. [Solving/Reducing equations in Z/pZ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/solving-reducing-equations-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz/16003#16003). 
Here I just set (I don't insist it is neccessary) :

```
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {1000, 1000000}];
```

and playing with `Reduce` I just found after roughly two minutes

```
Reduce[ 2^x + y^113 == z^2 && GCD[x, y] == 1 && 500 >= x > 0 && 
        32 >= y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> ```
>  (x == 3 && y == 1 && z == 3) || 
>    (x == 113 && y == 2 && z == 144115188075855872) || 
>    (x == 229 && y == 4 && z == 31153781151208965771182977975320576) ||
>    (x == 234 && y == 1 &&
>       z == 166153499473114484112975882535043072) || 
>    (x == 236 && y == 1 && z == 332306998946228968225951765070086144) ||
>    (x == 238 && y == 1 && z == 664613997892457936451903530140172288) || 
>    (x == 240 && y == 1 && z == 1329227995784915872903807060280344576) ||
>    (x == 242 && y == 1 && z == 2658455991569831745807614120560689152) ||
>    (x == 339 && y == 8 && 
>      z == 1496577676626844588240573268701473812127674924007424) ||
>    (x == 455 && y == 16 && 
>      z == 32351936000580767753600418104423556808364573307048686977324332\
>     2990592)
> ```

This result suggest that the only solutions are of the form `y == 2^n` for natural `n`. In fact, I've looked for solutions with higher bounds for `x` and `y` and all solutions were of the form `y == 2^n`. It seems to be easy to prove, nonetheless I put aside this step up to you. This can significantly simplify the search for solutions. Moreover it might be quite resonable to look for `z` expressed by its prime components. Now we can provide more solutions (it took a few minutes)

```
sols = {x, n, z} /. { ToRules @
 Reduce[2^x + (2^n)^113 == z^2 && GCD[x, 2^n] == 1 && 
         2000 >= x > 0 && 20 >= n >= 0 && z > 0, {x, n, z}, Integers]};
{#1, #2, FactorInteger @ #3} & @@@ sols // Column
```

> ```
> {3, 0, {{3, 1}}}
> {113, 1, {{2, 57}}}
> {229, 2, {{2, 113}, {3, 1}}}
> {234, 0, {{2, 117}}}
> {236, 0, {{2, 118}}}
> {238, 0, {{2, 119}}}
> {240, 0, {{2, 120}}}
> {242, 0, {{2, 121}}}
> {339, 3, {{2, 170}}}
> {455, 4, {{2, 226}, {3, 1}}}
> {565, 5, {{2, 283}}}
> {681, 6, {{2, 339}, {3, 1}}}
> {791, 7, {{2, 396}}}
> {907, 8, {{2, 452}, {3, 1}}}
> {1017, 9, {{2, 509}}}
> {1133, 10, {{2, 565}, {3, 1}}}
> {1243, 11, {{2, 622}}}
> {1359, 12, {{2, 678}, {3, 1}}}
> {1469, 13, {{2, 735}}}
> {1585, 14, {{2, 791}, {3, 1}}}
> {1695, 15, {{2, 848}}}
> {1811, 16, {{2, 904}, {3, 1}}}
> {1921, 17, {{2, 961}}}
> ```

These are the only solutions under the above bounds. With this approach it is quite natural to generalize and find all possible solutions proving a simple theorem.  At this point it is reasonable to stop since you haven't provided any piece of code.

**Edit**

It appears that the above analysis was performed for a different equation than the original one (see a comment by  anderstood) i.e. we should do
something like this (it took more than 15 minutes to evaluate):

```
 Reduce[ 2^x + 113^y == z^2 && GCD[x, y] == 1 && 2000 >= x > 0 && 
         100 >= y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> ```
> (x == 3 && y == 1 && z == 11) ||
> (x == 9 && y == 1 && z == 25)   ||
> (x == 242 && y == 1 && z == 2658455991569831745807614120560689152)
> ```

One can easily check that the first 2 solutions are correct however
there is an **awful bug** in the system behind the third solution. Namely 
`z == 2658455991569831745807614120560689152 == 2^121` therefore `2^242` cannot be equal to `113 + (2^121)^2`.

All of the following produce the same flawed results (in *Mathematica* versions *10.1*, *10.3*, *11.1*)

```
Reduce[2^242 + 113 == z^2 && z > 0, {z}, Integers]
Reduce[2^242 + 113^1 == z^2 && z ∈ Integers && z > 0, z]
Solve[z^2 == 2^242 + 113 && z ∈ Integers && z > 0, z]
```

while

```
Solve[2^242 + 113^1 == z^2 && z > 0, z, Integers]
```

does not.

I'm going to leave this post as a warning sign (until the bug is present) for the comunity, although we've got only partial results.

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be $113^y$ instead of $y^{113}$? Then $y=2^n$  no longer holds but your answer can be easily adapted and works.

Comment: With  `Reduce[2^x + 113^y == z^2 && GCD[x, y] == 1 && 2000 >= x > 0 && 
  100 >= y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers]` I got `(x == 3 && y == 1 && z == 11) || (x == 9 && y == 1 && 
   z == 25) || (x == 242 && y == 1 && 
   z == 2658455991569831745807614120560689152)`.

Comment: @anderstood I've found a bug in the system, and can't proceed further now. You can see that the last triple `(x == 242 && y == 1 && z == 2658455991569831745807614120560689152)` in your comment cannot be a solution since `z==2^242`. The problem  lies in `Reduce` and partially also in `Solve`.

Comment: Do you think it could be due to a truncation error (I mean that $2^{242}$ is so large that $113$ is seen as $0$).

Comment: @anderstood No, compare just `Solve[z^2 == 2^242 + 113 && z ∈ Integers && z > 0, z]` and `Solve[2^242 + 113^1 == z^2 && z > 0, z, Integers]`  both should provide the same results (no solutions) however the latter yields incorrect one. For exact arithmetic there are no approximations.

Answer (score 1):

Since Reduce and Solve don't work for higher values, simpliy test it directly, which goes quite fast.

First make a ContourPlot to get an impression, where solutions are to be expected.

```
ContourPlot3D[2^x + 113^y == z^2, {x, 0, 210}, {y, 0, 30}, {z, 0, 10^30}]
```

[image]

Solutions for given y are up to about x = 7*y and z = 10^y

Now do direct testing with y up to 100, x up to 700 and z up to very high z = Sqrt[2^700+113^100] = 2.2935*10^105

```
(sol = Flatten[
Table[If[
  GCD[x, y] == 1 && 
   IntegerQ[z = Sqrt[2^x + 113^y]], {{x, y, z}}, {}], {x, 0, 
  700}, {y, 0, 100}], 2]) // Timing
```

Quite fast you get the two solutions

```
(*     {62.641, {{3, 1, 11}, {9, 1, 25}}}     *)
```

Comment: thank you everone. I want solutions only in integers and it is possible to give a  general solution of this equation.