# Potential bug of function Reduce

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, expression-manipulation

**Bug introduced in 11.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.3.0**

---

Just a simple expression in version 11.2, Windows 10

```
Reduce[(-2)^n > 1, n, Integers]
```

returns

```
n ∈ Integers && n >= 2
```

But this result is not correct because it should be

```
n / 2 ∈ Integers && n >= 2
```

Furthermore, I remember that in previous version, e.g. 10.x, `Reduce` works properly.

---

**Update**

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B(-2)%5En%3E1,n,Integers%5D) behaves inconsistently.

Comment: Versions 5.2 and 8.0.4 solve this problem correctly, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question in the post.  This is just a bug report to which an answer cannot be supplied.

Comment: Correct result obtained from version 11.0.1.

Comment: Correct in 10.4, incorrect in 11.1.

Comment: Have you reported it to WRI Support?

Comment: This kind of bug I observed also when `Reduce` dealt with equations, see edit to this answer [Solving a diophantine equation with three variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155340/solving-a-diophantine-equation-with-three-variables/155350#155350)

Comment: @Kuba Yes, reported. But WRI seemed to show little interest, as I see it.

Comment: @AlexanderZeng because they did not reply or because of what they said?

Comment: @AlexanderZeng can you post this bug on community.wolfram.com. I am pretty sure a representative will see it !

Comment: @Kuba Because I think the reporter was treated as a help seeker, but s/he should be a help deliverer.

Comment: @AliHashmi Tried. But strangely I am unable to login.

Comment: @AlexanderZeng strange because i could log in yesterday.

Comment: @AliHashmi So, if necessary, maybe you can report it instead.

Comment: seems to be fixed in 11.3

Comment: @1110101001 Yes, it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely, adding a pointless equation causes the bug to be avoided:

```
aux = Reduce[(-2)^n > 1 && n == m, n, Integers]
(*  (m | n | C[1]/2) ∈ Integers && C[1] >= 2 && m == C[1] && n == C[1]  *)
```

I found it tricky to eliminate the unwanted variables programmatically. `Eliminate` does not work on inequalities, nor will `Reduce` or `Solve` eliminate a variable from `aux` probably for the same reason.

```
Or @@ (aux /. Solve[
     Cases[aux, eq_Equal],
     DeleteCases[n]@ Variables@ Cases[aux, Equal[x_, y_] :> {x, y}]
     ]) // Reduce
(*  n/2 ∈ Integers && n >= 2  *)
```