# Limited integer domain in Mathematica Reduce function

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a system of equations in Mathematica where all variables are restricted to be integers between `-3` and `11`. Which Domain restrictions do I have to pass to [Reduce](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) / how to properly specify this? I don't get it.

Comment: You can add these constraints as inequalities to your set of equations.

Comment: does `Reduce[{expr, And@@ Thread[ -3 <= variables <= 11]}, variables, Integers]` give what you need?

Comment: This [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/solving-reducing-equations-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz/16003#16003) should be quite sufficient w.r.t. your expectations.