# The format of the result returned from Reduce function

Tags: equation-solving

I use the `Reduce` function solve some problem, such as

```
Reduce[2k + 1 > 100 && k < 200, k, Integers]//ToString
```

How can I only get the result like `k = 1, k = 2......` instead of the format such as `C[1] ∈ Integers && 2831. <= C[1] <= 14999. && k == 1 + 2 C[1]`.

Comment: See this answer [Solving/Reducing equations in Z/pZ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/solving-reducing-equations-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz/16003#16003)

Answer (score 5):

When I try your example I do not get the same result you say you get.

Try

```
StringReplace[ToString[Flatten[ReplaceAll[
  FindInstance[2k+1>100&&k<200,k,Integers,200],
  Rule->Equal]]],"=="->"="]
```

which instantly returns

```
{k = 50, k = 51, k = 52, k = 53, k = 54, k = 55, k = 56, k = 57, k = 58,
 k = 59, k = 60, k = 61, k = 62, k = 63, k = 64, k = 65, k = 66, k = 67,
 k = 68, k = 69, k = 70, k = 71, k = 72, k = 73, k = 74, k = 75, k = 76,
 k = 77, k = 78, k = 79, k = 80, k = 81, k = 82, k = 83, k = 84, k = 85,
 k = 86, k = 87, k = 88, k = 89, k = 90, k = 91, k = 92, k = 93, k = 94,
 k = 95, k = 96, k = 97, k = 98, k = 99, k = 100, k = 101, k = 102, k = 103,
 k = 104, k = 105, k = 106, k = 107, k = 108, k = 109, k = 110, k = 111,
 k = 112, k = 113, k = 114, k = 115, k = 116, k = 117, k = 118, k = 119,
 k = 120, k = 121, k = 122, k = 123, k = 124, k = 125, k = 126, k = 127,
 k = 128, k = 129, k = 130, k = 131, k = 132, k = 133, k = 134, k = 135,
 k = 136, k = 137, k = 138, k = 139, k = 140, k = 141, k = 142, k = 143,
 k = 144, k = 145, k = 146, k = 147, k = 148, k = 149, k = 150, k = 151,
 k = 152, k = 153, k = 154, k = 155, k = 156, k = 157, k = 158, k = 159,
 k = 160, k = 161, k = 162, k = 163, k = 164, k = 165, k = 166, k = 167,
 k = 168, k = 169, k = 170, k = 171, k = 172, k = 173, k = 174, k = 175,
 k = 176, k = 177, k = 178, k = 179, k = 180, k = 181, k = 182, k = 183,
 k = 184, k = 185, k = 186, k = 187, k = 188, k = 189, k = 190, k = 191,
 k = 192, k = 193, k = 194, k = 195, k = 196, k = 197, k = 198, k = 199}
```

as one long string. See if that works for you. If this isn't what you are looking for then try to explain what you need and I will see if I can fix this for you.

Look up each of those functions in the help system to understand exactly how and why this works

Comment: You could use `Apply[List, ...]` to have it strictly be a list, correct? Or, perhaps it starts as a `List`, does it not? I like this answer a lot, but I think OP was hoping for the `List` outcome, even if this method might be better. Oh, hah, you literally just edited it. I like the usefulness of `Apply[Or, ...]` though, too.

Comment: @CATrevillian There are always a dozen different ways to do anything in Mathematica. We can all try to guess what he really wanted. I'm not exactly certain what he really wants from this. Because he shows getting a string out of this I'm wondering if he is going to take that and paste it into something else. Hopefully something in this will help him.

Comment: that is one of my favorite things about Mathematica! I have found myself taking a function I want to learn about, then using it to do as many different tasks as I can! That usually means that there’s another function that just **does** what I am trying to do, but that takes the fun out of it hah!

Comment: @CATrevillian Maybe you could turn that idea into a service. Once a week subscribers would get an email containing one odd MMA function along with a dozen astonishing ways to use that which you would never imagine, but actual practical uses, not just nonsense. Maybe include a few quiz questions at the end asking how to use that function, graded from fairly easy to completely mind boggling, making you think and expand your skill. I'd subscribe. Sign me up.

Answer (score 5):

*Update:* The system option (see *Original answer* below) can be set temporarily via the `Method` option of `Reduce` to get an enumeration of the solutions:

```
Reduce[2 k + 1 > 100 && k < 200, k, Integers, 
 Method -> {"DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 150}]
```

*Original answer*: Set `"DiscreteSolutionBound"` larger than the number of solutions:

```
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 150}]

Reduce[2 k + 1 > 100 && k < 200, k, Integers]

(*  k == 50 || ...|| k == 199  *)
```

(To reset: `SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 10}]`.)

You can also get the solutions from `Solve` without set the system option:

```
sol = Solve[2 k + 1 > 100 && k < 200, k, Integers]

(*  {{k -> 50}, ..., {k -> 199}}  *)
```

*Update*: `Solve` has a bound, `"SolveDiscreteSolutionBound" -> 1000000`, which can be set, if needed, via either of the following:

```
Solve[..., Method -> {"SolveDiscreteSolutionBound" -> n}]
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"SolveDiscreteSolutionBound" -> n}]
```

*Addendum:*
To get a string like the OP indicates, one might do the following:

```
sol /. Rule -> (HoldForm[Set[##]] &) //
 Flatten //
 ToString // 
 StringTrim[#, "{" | "}"] &
```